# PHP not returning correctly

Tags: php, return

OK, this is making no sense and is the first time i have had this problem.

Please tell me i am being stupid or something.

Here is my function:

```
function getCountry($n, $origCode)
{
    global $countryData;
    if(strlen($n) > 0)
    {
        if(isset($countryData[$n]))
        {
            //$return = $countryData[$n];
            var_dump($n);
            return $n;
        }
        else
        {
            $n = substr($n, 0, -1);
            getCountry($n, $origCode);
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR exiting couldn't find code $origCode $count<br>";   
    }

}
```

This is the call

```
foreach($file as $line)
{
    $split = explode(",", $line);
    echo "using $split[1]<br>";
    $country = getCountry(trim($split[1]), trim($split[1]));
    var_dump($country);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

File array:

```
$file = array("AA,93",
                "BB,9370",
                "CC,9378",
                "DD,9377",
                "EE,937",
                "FF,9379",
                "GG,355",
                "HH,35568",
                "II,35567"
            );
```

Country data array is

```
array('93'=>array('id'=>2')
    '355'=> array('id'=>'3)
);
```

The var_dumps are:

```
using 93 
string '93' (length=2)
string '93' (length=2)

using 9370 
string '93' (length=2)
null

using 9378 
string '93' (length=2)
null

using 9377 
string '93' (length=2)
null

using 937 
string '93' (length=2)
null

using 9379 
string '93' (length=2)
null

using 355 
string '355' (length=3)
string '355' (length=3)

using 35568 
string '355' (length=3)
null

using 35567 
string '355' (length=3)
null
```

What i dont understand at all is why when i var_dump just before i return the value it is ok but once a var_dump out of the function i get null

This is confusing me and i have no idea.

Any ideas??

Regards

Liam

Comment: At first glance, I believe you're missing a `return` on your call to `getCountry` in the `else` ... it should be `return getCountry($n, $origCode);`

Comment: in the first else the function doesn't return anything

Comment: dleiftah - I feel like an idiot haha. Many thanks it was something that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't return the value, when you call your function recursive you should return the result of your recursivelly called function.

In your else condition, you should return:

```
    else
    {
        $n = substr($n, 0, -1);
        return getCountry($n, $origCode);
    }
```

And your entire function became:

```
function getCountry($n, $origCode)
{
    global $countryData;
    if(strlen($n) > 0)
    {
        if(isset($countryData[$n]))
        {
            //$return = $countryData[$n];
            var_dump($n);
            return $n;
        }
        else
        {
            $n = substr($n, 0, -1);
            return getCountry($n, $origCode);
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR exiting couldn't find code $origCode $count<br>";   
    }

}
```